# number of integral solutions

Tags: algorithm, combinations

Question from the interview at f2f interview at MS:

Determine the number of integral solutions of

`x1 + x2 + x3 + x4 + x5 = N`

where `0 <= xi <= N`

So basically we need to find the number of partitions of N in at most 5 parts
Supposed to be solved with paper and pencil. Did not make much headway though, does anybody have a solution for this?

Comment: Supposed to be solved with pencil and paper for a particular N, or in general?

Comment: In mathematics, I believe we call these "weak composition on N into k (in this case k is equal to 5) parts". Partitions of N usually implies that having the order of the values doesn't matter. Technically speaking, it actually implies that the numbers are written in descending order, but I think the point is the same. Basically, if you switch x1 and x2 (and x1 != x2), you have the same partition but a different composition.

Just to drive the point home, I guess, partitions are like multisets and compositions are like permutations.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assume numbers are strictly > 0.
Consider an integer segment **[0, N]**. The problem is to split it into **4** segments of positive length. Imagine we do that by putting 4 splitter dots between adjacent numbers. How many ways to do that ? **C(N-1, 4)**.

Now, some numbers can be 0-s. Let **k** be number of non-zero numbers. We can choose them in **C(5,k)** ways, for each having **C(N-1, k)** splittings. Accumulating by all **k** in **[0,5]** range, we get
**Sum[ C(5,k) * C(n-1,k); k = 0 to 5]**

Comment: @lavin: Why ? There are N+1 points where segments can begin/end - 0,1,...,N

Comment: Check when N=1, the answer should be 5.

Comment: Oops, I missed the 0 case when segments can be equal. Will edit now.

Comment: wow ... you are quicker than me to post the correction with the explanation :D  +1 for smart&quick thinking!

Answer (score 2):

@Grigor Gevorgyan indeed gives the right way to figure out the solution.

think about when

```
1 <= xi
```

that's exactly dividing N points into 5 segments. it's equivalent to insert 4 "splitter dots" out of N-1 possible places ( between adjacent numbers). So the answer is C(N-1,4)

then what about when

```
0 <= xi
```

?

If you have the solution of X+5 points in

```
1 <= xi
```

whose answer is `C(N-1,4)=C(X+5-1,4)=C(X+4,4)`

then you simply remove one point from each set, and you have a solution of X points, with

```
0 <= xi
```

which means,the answer now is exactly equal to `C(X+4,4)`

Answer (score 2):

[Topcoder tutorials](http://community.topcoder.com/tc?module=Static&d1=tutorials&d2=combinatorics)

Look for the section "Combination with repetition" : The specific case is explained under that section with diagrmatic illustration .(A picture is worth quite a few words!)

Answer (score 2):

You have the answer [here](http://www.physicsforums.com/showthread.php?t=428074).

It is classical problem -

Number of options to put N balls in M boxes = c(M+N-1,N).

Answer (score 1):

The combinations solution is more appropriate if a pen and paper solution was asked. It's also the classic solution. Here is a dynamic programming solution.

Let `dp[i, N] = number of solutions of x1 + x2 + ... +xi = N`.

Let's take `x1 + x2 = N`:

We have the solutions:

```
0 + N = N
1 + N - 1 = N
...
N + 0 = N
```

So `dp[2, N] = N + 1` solutions.

Let's take `x1 + x2 + x3 = N`:

We have the solutions:

```
0 + (0 + N) = N
0 + (1 + N - 1) = N
...
0 + (N + 0) = N
...
```

Notice that there are `N + 1` solutions thus far. Moving on:

```
1 + (0 + N - 1) = N
1 + (1 + N - 2) = N
...
1 + (N - 1 + 0) = N
...
```

Notice that there are another `N` solutions. Moving on:

```
...
N - 1 + (0 + 1) = N
N - 1 + (1 + 0) = N
=> +2 solutions
N + (0 + 0) = N
=> +1 solution
```

So we have `dp[3, N] = dp[2, N] + dp[2, N - 1] + dp[2, N - 2] + ... + dp[2, 0]`.

Also notice that `dp[k, 0] = 1`

Since for each row of the matrix we need `N` summations, the complexity for computing `dp[k, N]` is `O(k*N)`, which is just as much as would be needed for the combinatorics solution.

To keep the complexity for each row `O(N)`, store `s[i] = sum of the first i elements on the previous row`. The memory used can also be reduced to `O(N)`.